# Is there a more Scala-esque way to impelent this vector processing function?

Tags: scala, vector, scala-breeze

I'm really new to Scala, and I've been trying to implement a function which is given two Scala Breeze DenseVectors that are equal length. Both vectors contain double values and NaNs. The function iterates over both vectors and checks if at the current index, both vectors have a double value. If so, it appends the respective values to two return value vectors.

I.e., Given vectors v1 = (3.0, 87.0, NaN, NaN, 19.0) and v2 = (15.0, NaN, NaN, NaN, 9.0) the function returns v1_new = (3.0, 19.0), v2_new = (15.0, 9.0).

My current implementation, which does seem to work, looks like this:

```
def joint_space(vec_a : DenseVector[Double], vec_b : DenseVector[Double]) = {
  var a_placeholder = List[Double]()
  var b_placeholder = List[Double]()

  for (index <- 0 to vec_a.length-1) {
    if (!vec_a(index).isNaN && !vec_b(index).isNaN) {
      a_placeholder = a_placeholder :+ vec_a(index)
      b_placeholder = b_placeholder :+ vec_b(index)
    }
  }

  val joint_vec_a = DenseVector(a_placeholder:_*)
  val joint_vec_b = DenseVector(b_placeholder:_*)

  (joint_vec_a, joint_vec_b)
}
```

This seems kind of clunky to me, and I'm wondering how would one implement this in a more Scala-esque way?

Answer (score 2):

I just looked at Scaladoc at http://www.scalanlp.org/api/breeze/, but something like this should work:

```
val notNans = vec_a.mapValues(x => !x.isNaN) :&& vec_b.mapValues(x => !x.isNaN)
val indices = notNans.findAll(x => x)
(vec_a(indices), vec_b(indices))
```

Or simpler, `val indices = (vec_a :+ vec_b).findAll(x => !x.isNaN)`.

Comment: `:+` is deprecated. `+:+` instead of. `:&&` - `&:&`.

Comment: @Zernike Is there a more up-to-date Scaladoc online? https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet also has old operators. Though I did think of the bad precedence consequences when looking at them.

Comment: I doubt. Just tried your code in IDE and got warnings. `"org.scalanlp" %% "breeze" % "0.13.1"`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a slower implementation, you can use `zip`/`unzip` for a one liner solution:

```
scala> val v1 = List(3.0, 87.0, Double.NaN, Double.NaN, 19.0)
v1: List[Double] = List(3.0, 87.0, NaN, NaN, 19.0)

scala> val v2 = List(15.0, Double.NaN, Double.NaN, Double.NaN, 9.0)
v2: List[Double] = List(15.0, NaN, NaN, NaN, 9.0)

scala> val (o1, o2) = v1.zip(v2).filterNot { case (a, b) => (a * b).isNaN }.unzip
o1: List[Double] = List(3.0, 19.0)
o2: List[Double] = List(15.0, 9.0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, while this works great with lists, I'm using DenseVectors from Scala Breeze (https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Data-Structures#densevector). I just might drop the DenseVectors and just use lists though. Or wrap your function into a function-call which transforms DenseVectors into regular lists.

Thank you!